# JPM cannot find Firefox binaries when it is under p: partition

Tags: firefox, mozilla, jpm

First time I have installed jpm. I created my first extension according tutorial and it is not possible to finish it so when I run command: jpm run it prints error. I have more installations of Firefox installed and profiles are not in standard locations so I thought it could be good to check if jpm can locate Firefox 43 and my profiles. First thing I did is this:

```
U:\addons\test>jpm test -b "P:\INTERNET\BROWSERS\FF 47\"
JPM [info] Starting jpm test on My Jetpack Addon
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
JPM [error] No Firefox binary found at null
JPM [error] Error: spawn P:\INTERNET\BROWSERS\FF 47" ENOENT
```

Starting from U: . however I noticed that the program works only with relative path like /../../../ so my question here is, can the program work with installation of Firefox under P: partition? How to fix it?

Also I have tried to rename the program folder to FF47:

```
P:\addons\test>jpm run -b /INTERNET/BROWSERS/FF47
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on My Jetpack Addon
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
JPM [error] No Firefox binary found at null
JPM [error] Error: spawn /INTERNET/BROWSERS/FF47 ENOENT
```

same result

Do you have any tips how to fix jpm to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of jpm on Windows does not recognize the directory of Firefox. You need to add firefox.exe on the end of the path.

```
U:\addons\test>jpm run -b "/INTERNET/BROWSERS/FF 47/firefox.exe"
```

or

```
U:\addons\test>jpm run -b "/INTERNET/BROWSERS/FF 47/firefox.exe" -p I:\accounts\Firefox\Profiles\admin
```